# Enforce a specific syntax highlighting for a single file within Eclipse editor

Tags: c++, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I have a file `mysrc.cc.orig`, which I want to open in the editor of Eclipse CDT and have it recognized (i.e., syntax-highlighted; parsing it to show the outline would be a plus, but it may have complications) as a C++ source file.

**Is there a way to quickly instruct Eclipse to do so for this specific file?**

Possible workarounds that are not satisfactory for me (mostly due to them being cumbersome):

1. I know I could rename it to `mysrc.orig.cc`, for instance. But that would be cumbersome for my needs.
2. I also know I could add `.orig` as C++ sources. That is not an option either.
3. I am not sure I can add complete file names as C++ sources, but even if possible that is not an option either.
4. [In Eclipse: Change the syntax highlighting for an individual file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225989/in-eclipse-change-the-syntax-highlighting-for-an-individual-file) ... Uses an external editor. Not what I am looking for.
5. Similar suggestion... https://superuser.com/questions/376608/eclipse-non-extension-file-syntax-highlight

Comment: Could you just add the filename pattern `mysrc.cc.orig` to be treated as cpp?

Comment: @ruohola - That is item 3 in the list... The need for a quick method stems from the fact this may happen frequently. Having to set and then unset such setting for each file becomes too cumbersome.

Comment: And you can't just make `.orig.cc` match cpp, because not every `*.orig.cc` file should be recognized as cpp?

Comment: @ruohola - I can do that. But I foresee there will be other .cc.orig files, so I would have to keep renaming them to .orig.cc to get syntax highlighting, and then back to their original name... something to avoid if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: Why can't you just make every `.cc.orig` file to be always recognized as cpp?